# Get network interface name and MAC address on command line

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

If I run the command

```
ip link | awk '{print $2}'
```

in Ubuntu 18.04, I get this output:

```
lo:
00:00:00:00:00:00
wlp1s0:
2c:6e:85:bf:01:00
enp2s0:
14:18:77:a3:01:02
```

I want it formatted like this (without `lo`)

```
wlp1s0: 2c:6e:85:bf:01:00
enp2s0: 14:18:77:a3:01:02
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Interestingly, you can also do it by **`ifconfig | grep HW | awk '{ print $1" : "$5 }'`**. Since loopback doesn't have a `HW` address, grep will ignore `lo`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can get the MAC address from `/sys/class/net/<dev>/address`:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/enp0s3/address
08:00:27:15:dc:fd
```

So, something like:

```
find /sys/class/net -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name lo -printf "%P: " -execdir cat {}/address \;
```

Gives me:

```
enp0s3: 08:00:27:15:dc:fd
docker0: 02:42:61:cb:85:33
```

Or, using `ip`'s one-line mode, which is convenient for scripting:

```
$ ip -o link | awk '$2 != "lo:" {print $2, $(NF-2)}'
enp0s3: 08:00:27:15:dc:fd
docker0: 02:42:61:cb:85:33
```

Comment: The /sys directory has been a feature of the Linux kernel since before version 2.6 and as such should be available on all distributions.

Answer (score 7):

#### Using ip link

```
ip -o link | grep ether | awk '{ print $2" : "$17 }'
```

- where `-o` gives on-line result for every interface.
- `grep ether` filters out only those interface that have a Ethernet address assigned to it.
- And `awk` simply prints the 2nd & 17th column from the lines with a colon in between.

OR

```
ip -br link | grep -v LOOPBACK | awk '{ print $1 " : " $3 }'
```

where

- `-br` gives the `brief` information of interfaces.
- `grep -v LOOPBACK` ignores the word `LOOPBACK` that is present only in `lo` interface.
- And `awk` prints first & 3rd column.

#### Using ifconfig

```
ifconfig | grep HW | awk '{ print $1" : "$5 }'
```

where `grep HW` filters out only those interface that have a hardware address assigned to it.

#### The Hack

`grep HW` or `grep ether` actually ignores the `lo` because

> Loopback interface that [doesn't have a HW Address](https://askubuntu.com/q/889970/769206) assigned to it.

Comment: I liked you patten matching!

Answer (score 4):

With no arguments *xargs* will replace all newlines, tabs and multiple spaces to single space. By adding *-n 2* it will slice that line after each second word. So:

```
ip link | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I made an ugly hacky one liner:

```
 ip link | awk -F' ' '{print $2 $17}' | paste -d " "  - - | grep -v lo:
```

If you count the fields using space as separators you will see the fields you need are the 2nd and 17th.

But they will be printed one under the other, the paste places the adjacent lines as colums. The paste fix that placing adjacent lines side by side in a  line.
I could not find a smart way to avoid getting the lo line so I just excluded it before printing with grep

Testing here:

```
ip link | awk -F' ' '{print $2 $17}' | paste -d " "  - - | grep -v lo:
enp2s0: 50:9a:4c:b5:af:ea
wlp3s0: e8:9e:b4:66:e3:ea
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Quick Answer]:

An approach to get the MAC address without knowing the interface name:

```
cat /sys/class/net/$(ip route show default | awk '/default/ {print $5}')/address
```

---

The following command returns interface name:

```
ip route show default | awk '/default/ {print $5}'
```

Comment: Only one that worked for me and easy to use !
Still for anyone who is not able to get it.
Go to the base directory where `sys` directory is and use the command Benyamin gave.

Comment: Won't work if either LAN cable is not connected for ethernet NICs or WLAN isn't associated if it's WLAN device.

Answer (score 2):

```
cat /sys/class/net/*/address
```

for all devices

There is also naming schema for network devices, e.g. here https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-understanding_the_predictable_network_interface_device_names.

> The names have two-character prefixes based on the type of interface:
>
> ```
> en for Ethernet,
> wl for wireless LAN (WLAN),
> ww for wireless wide area network (WWAN).
> ```

Therefore one could use `cat /sys/class/net/en*/address` to print MAC(s) of ethernet NIC(s) only.

Answer (score 1):

**OVH Ubuntu 18**

```
ifconfig | grep ether | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Answer (score -1):

Another simple way to create a table for NIC/MAC data - in my case the Network interface name starts with en

for i in `ls /sys/class/net | egrep -i ^en`; do echo "$i   $(cat /sys/class/net/${i}/address)"; done

Comment: please check the command. has a mistake